# check network connection while downloading file (c#)

Tags: c#, networking, download, webclient

I would like to check my internet connection **while** using WebClient in order to download a file. (WebClient.DownloadFile()).
I want to check if the connection still available in the middle of the downloading process.
How do I do that ? (in C#)
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why? If I recall correctly, the WebClient will throw an exception anyway if the connection is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot generally detect that the internet is available or not. But heuristically, you can start a second thread which tries to GET google.com with a read timeout of 5s every 15s or so. That way your connection check can have different, harder timeouts than your main download.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There is no way in TCP to check the status of a connection other than by trying to use it. Set a read timeout, and respond accordingly to the resulting SocketTimeoutException; and respond to any other IOException by closing the connection and maybe retrying, depending on your specific requirements.